# User Directory of my project in eclipse is giving me incorrect value

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to load the image from my project
Evnethough the image exists, it is throwing FilenotFound execption. I tried to print the directory using  System.getProperty("user.dir");  which is giving me incorrect value. Any idea why?

Comment: *how* are you loading the image? Show some code.

Comment: not getting enough idea based on above description. Are u using tomcat container and trying to load images from out side your container directories?

Comment: I know why my image is not getting loaded because i try to load it using /images/sample.png. expected source name should be $(workspace_location)/images/sample.png. here my workspace directory is giving incorrect value

Answer (score 0):

The `user.dir` will vary whether inside the IDE or stand-alone. For a read-only file/image *inside* the project use `Class.getResource(URL)`. In this way you can deploy the application as archive (jar, war, ear) and still read the file.

```
URL url = SomeClass.getResource("/.../... .png");
InputStream in = SomeClass.getResourceAsStream("/.../... .png");
```

The path must be case-sensitive. Path separator is slash. The image directory must be "compiled" into the application (= be a resource directory).

Comment: One of the classes in the application. Maybe `getClass()`. You could get a file in the same subdirectory as the current package with a relative URL: `xx.yy.zz.A.getResource("images/mm.jpg")` would search a `xx/yy/zz/images/mm.jpg`.